# How to disable internet for a user on a system

Tags: networking, internet, security, users, firewall

I know about changing owners/permissions on particular programs/files, but how can I control which users have access to the network card ([NIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_interface_controller)) or have the power to create [network sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As described [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/block-outgoing-network-access-for-a-single-user-from-my-server-using-iptables.html), you can block all Internet access for certain users using this `iptables` command:

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner {USERNAME} -j REJECT
sudo ip6tables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner {USERNAME} -j REJECT
```

If you want this command to run automatically when the system starts up, you should add it to the end of your `/etc/rc.local` file.

While this won't make it impossible for those users to create sockets, it will block all outgoing traffic (like a firewall).

Comment: how would you then reverse this command?

Comment: @user2662639 Simply reboot. Unless you've added the line to `/etc/rc.local`, it's not persistent, and if you have, then you can just remove that line.

Comment: @user2662639 (I think it's possible without rebooting but it's been three years since I wrote this answer and so I really can't remember anymore.)

Comment: run this: sudo iptables -D OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner {USERNAME} -j REJECT ||||||||| to delete the rule that you've added, notice the "-D" switch.

Comment: @Frxstrem it would be interesting to edit the answer and include how to do it with newer versions (with systemd): what would be the simplest way instead of `/etc/rc.local`? (or maybe would this still work, even with systemd?)

Comment: @Basj check my answer

Answer (score 1):

If [**firewalld**](https://firewalld.org/) is part of your setup, you can block network access for a specific user using a direct rule, es:

```xml
/etc/firewalld/direct.xml
‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<direct>
  <chain ipv="ipv4" 
         table="filter" 
         chain="restrict_user_ipv4"/>
  <rule ipv="ipv4" 
        table="filter" 
        chain="OUTPUT" 
        priority="1">-m owner --uid-owner user -j restrict_user_ipv4</rule>
  <rule ipv="ipv4" 
        table="filter" 
        chain="restrict_user_ipv4" 
        priority="3">-j DROP</rule>
  <chain ipv="ipv6" 
         table="filter" 
         chain="restrict_user_ipv6"/>
  <rule ipv="ipv6" 
        table="filter" 
        chain="OUTPUT" 
        priority="1">-m owner --uid-owner user -j restrict_user_ipv6</rule>
  <rule ipv="ipv6" 
        table="filter" 
        chain="restrict_user_ipv6" 
        priority="3">-j DROP</rule>
</direct>
```

Don't forget to reload with

```
# firewall-cmd --reload
```

#### References

- [Block Outgoing Network Access For a Single User Using Firewalld - Red Hat Customer Portal](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/3414921)

Comment: Big thank you! Googling half day for this. And here are my commands to block internet for a specific user but allow loopback:

firewall-cmd --direct --permanent --add-chain ipv4 filter no_internet
firewall-cmd --direct --permanent --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -m owner --uid-owner some-user -j no_internet
firewall-cmd --direct --permanent --add-rule ipv4 filter no_internet 2 -d 127.0.0.1/32 -j ACCEPT
firewall-cmd --direct --permanent --add-rule ipv4 filter no_internet 3 -j DROP
firewall-cmd --reload