# Make ufw follow iptable rules

Tags: networking, 18.04, iptables, firewall, ufw

I have a bunch of configuration in ufw that I want to avoid porting to iptables (unless there is a easy way to export from ufw and import in iptables). Simplicity of ufw etc. being the reason.

Now I want to block outgoing network for a user on the system using - [How to disable internet for a user on a system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223434/how-to-disable-internet-for-a-user-on-a-system)

But the problem is that if I have ufw enabled, it ignores iptable rules.

How do I ask ufw to follow iptable rules as well or maybe implement that user block in ufw?

Comment: Interesting question! There's a closely related question, with a comprehensive answer, over at serverfault: https://serverfault.com/questions/198398/ubuntu-how-to-add-an-iptables-rule-that-ufw-cant-create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @aplaice's comment, I added the following line in `/etc/ufw/after.rules`

```
-A ufw-after-output -m owner --uid-owner idea -j REJECT
# don't delete the 'COMMIT' line or these rules won't be processed
COMMIT
```

You have to add it for the chain `ufw-after-output` and before `COMMIT`.

Restart ufw service after that.