# Require admin Password to open firefox on user account Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04

My siblings have a user account on my ubuntu computer, and they aren't allowed to use the internet. I need to block firefox on their account.

In order to open firefox on their user account, I would like it to require the admin password.

How can I do this in Ubuntu 18.04?

They play on online Minecraft servers, so I can't disable internet all together

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable internet for a user on a system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223434/how-to-disable-internet-for-a-user-on-a-system)

Comment: How good do they know linux, or how easily can they learn to work around some simple obstacle?

Comment: @sudodus - they will figure it out. Kids with strict content blocks are future hackers and software devs

Comment: Yes @Nmath , I think so too, at least if they are at least 10 years old, maybe even at younger age. I think your link is a better alternative than to require admin password to open firefox. So no sudo permissions and disabled internet for the user.

Comment: @Nmath is there a way I could only allow internet access for Minecraft?

Comment: Would it be an option for you to create a dual boot system with a second system where you have removed firefox (and other possible web browsers), and in the second system give them a standard user without sudo access. Even better would be a separate computer (maybe second-hand 'refurbished' computer).

Comment: If you're looking for an application firewall check out these other questions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/917575/is-there-any-application-level-firewall-for-ubuntu-16-04-with-gui | https://askubuntu.com/questions/45072/how-to-control-internet-access-for-each-program maybe this too: https://askubuntu.com/questions/23932/how-do-i-replace-the-desktop-by-an-application/